# Can I use SQL Server 2012 on-Premise with Azure Mobile service for offline Synchronization?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Can I use SQL Server 2012 on-Premise database with Azure Mobile service(.net backend) for offline Synchronization?

In the following tutorial in prerequisites using SQL Server 2014, cant I use SQL Server 2012.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-hybrid-connections-get-started/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use older versions of SQL Server. The tutorial just assumes SQL Server 2014, so the steps for configuration may be different.

For more information, see the following tutorials:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/
- [PowerShell CmdLets | Hybrid Connection Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn789178.aspx)